# iOS Swift - Call function for another class and see null variables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have three classes, where i have a container, mainview and a left menu.

[App looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q25Jc.png)

When i press a button in the left menu, this execute an action in mainview:

```
var viewController: ViewController = ViewController()

func menuLeftButton1(){
self.viewController.doActionInMainView()
}
```

But, when i want to change a variable of the mainview in that function in debuger says that the varieble of maninview is null.

I think that the variables of the mainview are destroyed and i can't use them when i return from the left menu.

> Other case is when i have a switch in the left menu and I enable it
>   and close the left menu and open again the switch looks like I haven't
>   enable it.

Can u help me with this case? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, the storyboard of mainview and other for side menu

Comment: Please check my answer, I think you need to use the viewcontroller from storyboard, if you face problem please ask in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in this code:

```
var viewController: ViewController = ViewController()
```

You need to instatiate viewcontroller from a xib or storyboard

For storyboard you can do this:

You need to set the identifier of the view controller in storyboard

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIdentifier")
```